# Symfony2 access to Global Variables from a twig template in phpunit test

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit, twig

I have a twig template with `{{ app.user }}`. The problem is, that in a phpunit test (a class, which extends `WebTestCase`) it is defined as NULL. Simulating Authentication with a Token (http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/testing/simulating_authentication.html) or simulating HTTP Authentification (http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/testing/http_authentication.html) does not help.
So how can I set a twig global variable from a phpunit test? And why simulating authentification is not working in this case?

Comment: versions:
symfony: 2.3.2
phpunit: 4.0.19
php: 5.5.6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a similar problem (logging in properly) what solved it finally for me was to change the way I log in(it's based on http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/testing/simulating_authentication.html but I handle the session differently):

```
public function setUp() {
    parent::setUp();

    $this->em = $this->get('doctrine')->getManager();
    $this->client = static::createClient(array('environment' => 'test'));
}

protected function logIn() {
    $repo = $this->em->getRepository('XXXXXXX');
    $user = $repo->findOneByUsername('YYYYYYY');

    $session = new Session(new MockFileSessionStorage());
    $firewall = 'main';
    $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, $firewall, array('ROLE_ADMIN'));
    $this->client->getContainer()->get('security.context')->setToken($token);
    $session->set('_security_' . $firewall, serialize($token));
    $session->save();

    $this->client->getContainer()->set('session', $session);
    $cookie = new Cookie($session->getName(), $session->getId());
    $this->client->getCookieJar()->set($cookie);

    return $user;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked for me, but I have also added one line 
`$this->client->getContainer()->get('security.context')->setToken($token);`

Comment: Had the same problem but all I needed to change in the example from the Symfony docs is to pass in the whole `$user`object as first parameter for the `UsernamePasswordToken` constructor, instead of just the username. But this solution helped me figure that out, so thanks very much!